# Is it possible to use dynamic object properties in Firestore

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to store dynamic variables, like a timestamp, as a property in Firestore?
I tried the following but that does not work. (`error: 'timeStamp' is assigned a value but never used`)

```
var timeStamp = new Date()
db.collection('test').doc('jdW0spuKzLcq7ycmDNm2').update({
        users: {
          timeStamp: {
            this: 'bla',
            that: 'blabla'
          }
        }
      })
```

What I am looking for is a way to store data as follows:

users{120220190800{this:'bla',that'blabla'},120220190802{this:'blablabla',that'bla'}

I am also wondering if it is possible to store data in the following way:

users{{this:'bla',that'blabla'},{this:'blablabla',that'bla'}

Comment: Please edit the question to address these questions.  What are you expecting that code to do?  Why doesn't it work the way you expect? Have you investigated the use of FieldValue.timestamp()?

Comment: @Doug Stevenson I edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used something like this:

```
db.collection('test').doc('doc').get().then ( (docSnap) => {
        var timeStamp = new Date()
        var doc = docSnap.data()        
        doc.users[timeStamp.toString()] = {'this': 'bla',that: 'blabla'} 
        db.collection('test').doc('doc').set(doc);
})
```

The result after few execution is bellow, so I think if you reformat the date should be something you need:

[image: Result]
Enjoy!

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks Witold!