# Add Angular reactive form with dynamic rows data to firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an angular reactive form I made using Angular Material.
In this form, I want the user to be able to add budget items below a budget title so the budget rows are dynamic. You can add rows and remove them dynamically.

The output of the form is like this:

```
    { 
   "name":"December 2019 House Budget",
   "startDate":"2019-12-04T10:52:04.016Z",
   "desc":"My household stuffs",
   "budgetList":[ 
      { 
         "itemName":"Groceries",
         "itemCost":200
      },
      { 
         "itemName":"Rent",
         "itemCost":600
      },
      { 
         "itemName":"Entertaiment",
         "itemCost":150
      },
      { 
         "itemName":"Water bills",
         "itemCost":50
      }
   ]
}
```

In my component.ts, I have `onSubmit()`:

```
onSubmit(value, formDirective: FormGroupDirective) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(value));
    this.mainservice.createBudget(value)
    .then(
      res => {
        formDirective.resetForm();
        this.addBudget.reset();
      }
    )
  }
```

Then in the service I have the `createBudget()` function as following.

```
createBudget(value) {
    return this.firestore.collection('budgets').add({
      name: value.name,
      startDate: value.startDate,
      desc: value.desc,
      budgetList: {
        itemName: value.budgetList.itemName,
        itemCost: value.budgetList.itemCost
      }
    })
  }
```

But I am getting this error:

```
ERROR FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field budgetList.itemName)
    at new FirestoreError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:163869:28)
    at ParseContext.push../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js.ParseContext.createError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:184098:16)
    at UserDataConverter.push../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js.UserDataConverter.parseScalarValue (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:184457:27)
    at UserDataConverter.push../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js.UserDataConverter.parseData (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:184323:29)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:184339:41
    at forEach (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:163973:13)
    at UserDataConverter.push../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js.UserDataConverter.parseObject (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:184338:13)
    at UserDataConverter.push../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js.UserDataConverter.parseData (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:184292:25)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:184339:41
    at forEach (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:163973:13)
```

The question is how am I supposed to send this kind of data to firestore? 
Additiona thing: How can I assign each additional item an ID?

I am newbie to Firebase ;)

Comment: the error is with `itemName` inside budgetList. I guess budgetList is an array inside your collection. Can you confirm me these assumptions?

Can you try `itemName: value.budgetList.itemName || ''` just for the sake of science? let me know

Comment: Yes I think so.... From the output json.

Comment: @FranciscoSantorelli after trying what you advised: I added 2 items: This is what was sent to Firestore
budgetList
itemCost
""
itemName
""
desc
"My desc"
name
"My budget"
startDate
4 December 2019 at 00:00:00 UTC+1

Comment: The ItemName and ItemCost are empty

Comment: I have an idea, but I have not tested it, can you please give it a shot and let me know?

Comment: Okay let me try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that `value` is exactly this object you have paste at beginning as "the output of the form". So the structure of the `value` is exactly the same as structure of the document you want to add to collection. So you should just add this object like this:

```
createBudget(value) {
    return this.firestore.collection('budgets').add(value)
}
```

I have tested this directly in node on GCP console like this:

```
const {Firestore} = require('@google-cloud/firestore');

var value = { 
   "name":"December 2019 House Budget",
   "startDate":"2019-12-04T10:52:04.016Z",
   "desc":"My household stuffs",
   "budgetList":[ 
      { 
         "itemName":"Groceries",
         "itemCost":200
      },
      { 
         "itemName":"Rent",
         "itemCost":600
      },
      { 
         "itemName":"Entertaiment",
         "itemCost":150
      },
      { 
         "itemName":"Water bills",
         "itemCost":50
      }
   ]
}

// Create a new client
const db = new Firestore();

db.collection('test').add(value)
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Wow! That went so smooth. Thank you for saving me.

Comment: A follow up quiz, is there a way to set name like `item1` instead of `0` ....? Thank you again @Witold

Comment: Yes, this should be possible as well. Pls check my other answer: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59170368/is-it-possible-to-use-dynamic-object-properties-in-firestore) there is timestamp used in this situation

Comment: Thank you for the guide.... But that would mean that I will not use `..add(value)`?

Answer (score 0):

I'll post it as an Answer for format, but I'm not sure this works please let me know:

According to [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data), you have to first create an `uid` for the list Item you wish to add. But for this, you need to first create (as per your example) a budget.

So I believe you should:

create your new budget the way you are doing it. But save that uid (the one that returns from the save somewhere), and then add a callback, to push the new list item.

like so:

```
// initialize budgetList inside the new budget as an empty object {}
createBudget(value) {
    return this.firestore.collection('budgets').add({
      name: value.name,
      startDate: value.startDate,
      desc: value.desc,
      budgetList: {}
    })
  }
```

---

```
const newBudget = createBudget(value); // get id for newBudget
const budgetList = this.firestore.collection('budgets')[newBudget]; // get the list;

const newBudgetListUid = budgetList.push().key;
newBudgetListUid.set(childList);
```

or:

```
// I'm assuming folders inside firestore work like this. But maybe they don't. I'm investigating to update if I'm wrong.
createBudget(value) {
    const list = this.firestore.collection('budgets').add({
      name: value.name,
      startDate: value.startDate,
      desc: value.desc,
      budgetList: {}
    });

    const budgetList = list.budgetList.push().key;
    const budgetList.set({
      itemName: value.budgetList.itemName,
      itemCost: value.budgetList.itemCost
    });
  }
```

I'm assuming lots of stuff here, but maybe the idea clarifies enough for you to find the solution (and comment it if so, so I can edit the comment).

Comment: Unfortunately both methods don't seem to work for mr.